# Never + nor + or

Tags: neither-nor

I would like to ask whether the following sentence is grammatically correct and natural for a native speaker to hear:

> I have never talked to X, nor do I know where X lives or what is X's favourite meal.

Thank you.

Comment: If the sentence mustn't be divided, I'd use 'I have never talked to X; neither do I know where X lives nor what is X's favourite meal.' But it's stilted in conversation.

Comment: Many would end with "nor what X's favorite meal is"

Comment: Edwin, I know you famously love to answer in comments, and you usually say this is to facilitate migration to ELL, even though its not strictly alowed Have you voted to close as suitable for ELL?

Comment: Except for where you put "is," it's fine. It's not unnatural. It's something a native speaker would say. So, as long as you move the "is," you're fine (i.e., "I have never talked to X, nor do I know where X lives or what X's favourite meal is."). By the way, it's only "favourite" in British English. If you're writing for an American audience, the spelling is "favorite," sans the U.